# is it good semantic to give a dt more than one dd in the dl?

Tags: html, html-lists, semantics, semantic-markup

So I'm thinking something like:

```
<dl>
    <dt>job title</dt>
    <dd>job duration</dd>
    <dd>job description</dd>
    <dd>company link</dd>
</dl>
```

The example is purely make up, so it might not be the best example. but I've come across couple times when there is need for using 2 dd for 1 dt. so do you guys this is good semantic or bad semantic?

Answer (score 5):

The W3C document [Lists in HTML Documents](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.3) give an example with multiple terms and descriptions, so I guess it's fine.  And it validates perfectly.

(Having said that, your example - which I appreciate is fictitious - is somewhat abusing `<DL>`, in that "job description" is not a definition of the term "job title".)

Comment: I'd disagree that "job description" isn't a definition of a "job title" - essentially, it's defining aspects of the job, and the title is merely a placeholder for the job itself - so it meets the semantics in that regard (imo). fei, another useful link is this article: http://www.maxdesign.com.au/presentation/definition/

Answer (score 2):

Semantic code is just code that makes sense when you read it. Let's take the most obvious example, a dictionary entry. Any given word in a dictionary will likely have multiple definitions.

Lists when you're listing things, paragraphs when you're writing a paragraph, etc.

In short, it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The W3C documentation also gives a very un-definition like use of DT/DD as being properly semantic: "Another application of DL, for example, is for marking up dialogues, with each DT naming a speaker, and each DD containing his or her words."  So it would seem that DT=Job Title and DD=Job description to be very semantically appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate you made up the example, but for the specific case of jobs, it so happens that there is a genuine machine parseable solution in use at the Central Office of Information in the UK.

http://code.google.com/p/argot-hub/wiki/ArgotVacancy

This is used to support aggregation of public sector jobs from many small sites to a central one at the CIO.

If, as another poster alludes to, you meant "semantic" as in "readable for the developer", then this is not optimal (though it is fairly readable) but if you meant to mean "predictably transformable to XML or RDF by a standard tool" then this is very good stuff.

See also the [RDFa distiller](http://www.w3.org/2007/08/pyRdfa/)